# python hangs after computer sleep/hibernate [Mac OS X]

Tags: python, macos, power-management

when running a python script, if my computer goes to sleep/hibernate (ie. screen gets turned off) and is turned back on the script hangs (freezes) and does not continue.

I believe this happens specifically when the script uses the network but I'm not certain.

I ended up using caffeine to prevent my computer from sleeping but I wonder if there is a better workaround for this issue?

I would love to be able to run a background script that doesn't hang when the computer comes back from hibernate.

Comment: Possibly when your computer sleeps, the network and/or disk is suspended. Check your power management settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a python issue.

take a look at `nohup` command

and at `&`

for example:

```
nohup python -u my_script.py  &
```

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this would fix the problem? I would expect the kernel to send SIGSTOP, not SIGHUP, when hibernating, and SIGCONT when waking up.